# Returning empty IQueryable<>

Tags: entity-framework

I have this method that tries to get a list of things:

```
 private static IQueryable<Thing> GetThings(int thingsType)
        {
                try
                {
                    return from thing in entities.thing.Include("thingStuff")
                           select thing;
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    return new EnumerableQuery<Thing>(?????);
                }
            }

        }
```

I want to return an empty IQueryable if I can't for whatever reason get the query to run. I don't want to return NULL because that could break the calling code. Is it possible or am I going totally wrong about this?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

These answers are good and do work, however I have always felt using Empty and not creating a new List is cleaner:

```
Enumerable.Empty<Thing>().AsQueryable();
```

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: But mind that if you use await / async with EF6 you will end up with following exception: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn313107.aspx - Check this link for async manner - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305495/how-to-return-empty-iqueryable-in-an-async-repository-method

Comment: For me, this solution did not work in a complex query. EF Core was throwing `InvalidOperationException` with a message `Processing of the LINQ expression XXX by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core`. I have just used `.Where(x => false)` which worked.

Answer (score 11):

Try the following:

```
private static IQueryable<Thing> GetThings(int thingsType)
    {
            IQueryable<Thing> things = new List<Thing>().AsQueryable();
            try
            {
                things = from thing in entities.thing.Include("thingStuff")
                       select thing;

                return things;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return things;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @mreyeros You never return anything if no exception is thrown.  Perhaps you meant to put your return in a finally?

Answer (score 7):

I would add block `finally {}` and put my return type in that code.

This will take care of the issue by returning the type that your application expects.

```
private static IQueryable<T> GetThings(int thingsType)
    {
            IQueryable<T> list = new List<Thing>().AsQueryable();
            try
            {
                list = from thing in entities.thing.Include("thingStuff")
                       select t;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
               // handle exception here;
            }
            finally {    
              return list;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Definitely agree, the exception should be handled in some fashion or another, and then the call to return the empty list should be returned in the finally block.

Comment: Thanks, it just a bit more defensive style of coding :)

Answer (score 4):

> Returning empty IQueryable<>
>   DbSet.Take(0)

Comment: Ma you add an explanation for the answer?

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be tidier:

```
private static IQueryable<T> GetThings(int thingsType)
{
    try
    {
        return from thing in entities.thing.Include("thingStuff")
                   select t;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
       // Exception handling code goes here

       return new List<Thing>().AsQueryable();
    }
}
```