# Asynchronous Paging with Entity Framework 6.1.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I'm new to EF so apologies in advanced if something isn't done correctly. I'm struggling to get paging to work asynchronously with EF 6.

I've implemented the paging mechanism as per this article: [How to Increase the Performance of Entity Framework with Paging](https://developingsoftware.com/entity-framework-paging/), which I thought was clean and to the point (but not perfect either) but I can't get this to work asynchronously which is a problem.

As per article, I've create the interface:

```
public interface IPageList
{
    int TotalCount { get; }
    int PageCount { get; }
    int Page { get; }
    int PageSize { get; }
}
```

I created the class:

```
public class PageList<T> : List<T>, IPageList
{
    public int TotalCount { get; private set; }
    public int PageCount { get; private set; }
    public int Page { get; private set; }
    public int PageSize { get; private set; }

    public PageList(IQueryable<T> source, int page, int pageSize)
    {
        TotalCount = source.Count();
        PageCount = GetPageCount(pageSize, TotalCount);
        Page = page < 1 ? 0 : page - 1;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        AddRange(source.Skip(Page * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList());
    }

    private int GetPageCount(int pageSize, int totalCount)
    {
        if (pageSize == 0)
            return 0;

        var remainder = totalCount % pageSize;
        return (totalCount / pageSize) + (remainder == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

and finally the extension:

```
public static class PageListExtensions
{
    public static PageList<T> ToPageList<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int pageNumber, 
    int pageSize)
    {
        return new PageList<T>(source, pageNumber, pageSize);
    }
}
```

So in my data layer, I've got the following function:

```
public async Task<List<LogEntity>> GetLogsAsync(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    using (_dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
    {                            
        var results = _dbContext.Logs.Select(l => new
        {
            LogId = l.LogId,
            Message = l.Message,
        })
        .OrderBy(o => o.DateTime)
        .ToPageList(pageNumber, pageSize).ToList().Select(x => new LogEntity()
        {
            LogId = x.LogId,
            Message = x.Message,
        });

        return await results.AsQueryable<LogEntity>().ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

When I run the above, I get:

> Additional information: The source IQueryable doesn't implement
>   IDbAsyncEnumerable. Only sources that
>   implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework
>   asynchronous operations. For more details see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068.

I've googled the error and while I've read numerous articles, I'm still struggling to get it to work.

Can anyone tell me exactly how to resolve this problem as I have no idea where to start at this stage.

Thanks

**UPDATE-1**

As Ivan highlighted in his comment, I don't think I need the 2 `Select`, so here is the simplified version:

```
var results = _dbContext.Logs.OrderBy(o=>o.DateTime)
    .ToPageList(pageNumber, pageSize).Select(l => new
{
    LogId = l.LogId,
    Message = l.Message,
});
```

Still doesn't sort my async problem. I'm currently looking at this article which will hopefully help:

[How to return empty IQueryable in an async repository method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305495/how-to-return-empty-iqueryable-in-an-async-repository-method)

**UPDATE-2**

I think I figured it out but it still not as responsive as I'd like it to be, so I'm not 100% sure whether or not it is done correctly. I thought that when swapping to my logs tab in my WPF app, the swapping would have been instantaneous but it's not!

Anyway here's what I've changed:

```
    public async Task<List<LogEntity>> GetLogsAsync(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        using (_dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            var results = _dbContext.Logs.OrderBy(o=>o.DateTime).ToPageList(pageNumber, pageSize).Select(l => new LogEntity
            {
                LogId = l.LogId,
                Message = l.Message,
            }).AsAsyncQueryable();

            return await results.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

If anything, the code is definitely simpler than my original one.

**Update-3:**

When I call this:

```
return new PageList<LogEntity>(_dbContext.Logs, pageNumber, pageSize);
```

It returns the TotalCount = 100,000, PageCount = 200, Page = 0, PageSize 500, but then it throws an error when the AddRange is called i.e.

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted
>   input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before 
>   the method 'Skip'.

So I fixed this by calling:

```
return new PageList<LogEntity>(_dbContext.Logs.OrderBy(o=>o.DateTime), 
pageNumber, pageSize);
```

When I tried to call @krillgar's simplest suggestion i.e.

```
return _dbContext.Logs
       .Select(l => new LogEntity // Cast here so your .ToPageList
       { // will start as the object type you want.
         LogId = l.LogId,
         Message = l.Message    
       })
       .OrderBy(l => l.DateTime)
       .ToPageList(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: The entity or complex type
>   'MyCompany.DataLayerSql.LogEntity' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to
>   Entities query.

on the `this.TotalCount = source.Count();` in the PageList class.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you don't need the `PagedList` class because you are not using it. Also what's the reason for the 2 `Select`s?

Comment: @IvanStoev I am using it. It's used at line 10 in the GetLogsAsync function. As for the 2 selects, that's a good question and I didn't want to ask multiple questions in here.  I've just had another go at it and I've simplified it. I'll upload it in a sec.

Comment: By not using it I mean you are not returning `PagedList<T>` which is the whole purpose of that class. If you want simply paged result, simply include `Skip` / `Take` in your query. e.g. `return await  _dbContext.Logs.OrderBy(o=>o.DateTime).Select(...).Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();`

Comment: @IvanStoev That is being done within the constructor, only without the `async`.

Comment: @krillgar I know, but that's the issue, and also, again the main purpose of that class is to be returned, because w/o additional properties it's just a list. Using it just to do `Skip` / `Take` doesn't make sense, even not counting the `Count()` call overhead.

Comment: That's a good point about the return type as well. That contract hides all the other information contained within the object.

Comment: @IvanStoev, you are correct. I totally missed that part and it's an important one! I'll review my code now and see how I can return this instead as returning the list is just not enough if I want to disable buttons based on the data that's returned and that was a point I made about the article not being perfect but I'm the one who needs to learn how to read :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `async` incorrectly here. Unless you're doing I/O, or very long operations you're typically only going to create extra overhead as the threads are created, managed, and merged.

Querying from the database is an I/O operation, however you haven't learned how Entity Framework behaves, so you're missing the benefit of making this operation asynchronous.

Entity Framework (and LINQ in general) uses a technique called [Deferred Execution](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/entity-framework-and-linq-to-entities-6-deferred-execution-laziness-loading-and-eager-loading). What that means in this case is that nothing is sent to your database until you want to act on the data. You're able to conditionally add `.Where()`, `.Skip()`, etc to your heart's content, and EF will just sit there preparing to build the SQL query.

To send that SQL statement to the database, you need to **act** on it, which you do in your `PageList` constructor twice. The first is:

```
TotalCount = source.Count();
```

That takes the SQL with all of your `WHERE` statements, etc, prepends a `SELECT COUNT (*)`, and fetches the result.

The second time is here:

```
AddRange(source.Skip(Page * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList());
```

At the end of the above line, the `.ToList()` will send another query to your database, retrieve all the columns and rows you ask for, and populate all of your entities. **THIS** is where you want your async, but [you can't make an `async` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8145668/1195056).

Your alternative would be to forego setting everything within the constructor and use a method instead, which can easily be made `async`.

In your original question, you started with this:

```
_dbContext.Logs.Select(l => new
    {
        LogId = l.LogId,
        Message = l.Message,
    })
    .OrderBy(o => o.DateTime)
```

You have also since updated to put the `OrderBy()` and `.ToPageList()` before your `.Select()`. However, you're still querying it as an anonymous object, so you once more need to continue casting after you should need to.

Going back to the root of your problem, we need to look at your return statement:

```
return await results.AsQueryable<LogEntity>().ToListAsync();
```

There's no need to do that, other than to put an artificial async call in there, which won't save you anything (see above). Your cast to `.AsQueryable<T>()` only adds to the processing, and doesn't give you anything.

The easiest way for you to use what you have is a little rearranging and elimination of redundant code. Your `.ToPageList()` already casts the object as a `List<T>`, so if you do things in the correct order, you'll save yourself a lot of grief:

```
return _dbContext.Logs
                 .Select(l => new LogEntity // Cast here so your .ToPageList
                              { // will start as the object type you want.
                                  LogId = l.LogId,
                                  Message = l.Message
                              })
                 .OrderBy(l => l.DateTime)
                 .ToPageList(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

That's really all that you need.

If you are dead-set on using `async`, then you should rework your class by adding a default constructor, and the following method:

```
public async Task CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int page, int pageSize)
{
    TotalCount = await source.CountAsync(); // async here would help
    PageCount = GetPageCount(pageSize, TotalCount);
    Page = page < 1 ? 0 : page - 1;
    PageSize = pageSize;
    AddRange(await source.Skip(Page * PageSize)
                         .Take(PageSize)
                         .ToListAsync()); // async here too!
}
```

That can be cleaned up with refactoring, but that's the gist. Then call it like this:

```
// Get your query set up, but don't execute anything on it yet.
var results = _dbContext.Logs.Select(l => new LogEntity
                                    {
                                        LogId = l.LogId,
                                        l.Message
                                    })
                             .OrderBy(l => l.DateTime);

var pageList = new PageList<LogEntity>();
await pageList.Create(results, pageNumber, pageSize);

return pageList;
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. Sorry for the delay getting back, but I'm struggling with another part which I omitted from the question. I need to convert the LogEntity (database model) to a Log object (domain model). I'll update as soon as I have figured out this part.

Comment: when I try your 'simplest' suggestion, I get the following error: `The entity or complex type 'MyCompany.DataLayerSql.LogEntity' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The class has a parameterless constructor? It's a C# class? If you want the end result to be a `Log` object, just substitute that instead.

Comment: I'm not even at the point of converting LogEntity to Log. I'm still trying to get suggestion to work. Would you mind terribly checking my `update-3` in my question and see if it makes any sense as to why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Try the `OrderBy()` before the Select.

Comment: Odd! That didn't work either. Not to worry. I'll go the method that works for now i.e. `return new PageListEntity<LogEntity>(_dbContext.Logs.OrderBy(o => o.DateTime), pageNumber, pageSize) as I'm more interested in getting the async part to work. I'll update later and see if what you suggested worked.

Comment: I can see what you mean about not needing async when using Linq and SQL so I will stick to your simplest solution for now. Many thanks once again to both of you for taking the time to help! Really appreciated.